# Creating (quadratic) Bezier curve using FastCast; cannot set position directly, only an acceleration

Tags: lua, roblox, bezier

I have been working on creating a quadratic Bezier curve in Roblox, in 3D, using a bit of a roundabout way. Doing this the normal way is a quite trivial task;

```lua
local function CalculateQuadraticBezierCurve(startPos, controlPos, endPos, t)
    local u = 1 - t
    local tt = t * t
    local uu = u * u

    local p = uu * startPos
    local q = 2 * u * t * controlPos
    local r = tt * endPos
    
    local tan = 2 * u * (controlPos - startPos) + 2 * t * (endPos - controlPos)

    return p + q + r, tan
end
```

You can just use this code to set the position of a part directly (p + q + r) and that gives the intended curve.

"Unfortunately", I really want to implement this using FastCast. Some knowledge on FastCast is probably handy for this question, but very quickly: FastCast is a module that creates a raycast every frame based on a initial velocity, direction and acceleration (https://devforum.roblox.com/t/making-a-combat-game-with-ranged-weapons-fastcast-may-be-the-module-for-you/133474). You can only change the direction and velocity initially, but you can change the acceleration on every update which is what I'm doing. This is my current implementation on creating the Bezier curve right now:

On starting the curve:

```lua
local startingCFrame = CFrame.new(startPos, endPos)
controlPos[i] = (startingCFrame + (direction * (ClientRange/1.5)) + (startingCFrame:ToWorldSpace(CFrame.Angles(0, 0, math.rad(120 * i + 90))).RightVector * 4)).Position -- The third point on the curve, the control position, is different for each projectile. I fire three here, so 120 degrees from each other
local distance = CalculateQuadraticBezierCurveLength(startPos, controlPos[i], endPos, 100)
totalTime = distance / BULLET_SPEED -- So here we approximate the duration (which turns out to not be correct because of the velocity speeding up beyond the specified BULLET_SPEED)
startingTime[i] = tick()
local passedTime = tick() - startingTime[i]
local alpha = passedTime / totalTime
local _, tan = CalculateQuadraticBezierCurve(startPos, controlPos[i], endPos, alpha)
CastBehavior.Acceleration = tan -- Uses the tangent as acceleration
CastBehavior.Count = i -- As I fire 3 projectiles at once, you want to keep track of which is which
```

The part that changes the acceleration every frame:

```lua
local passedTime = tick() - startingTime[cast.RayInfo.Count]
local alpha = passedTime / totalTime
local pos, tan = CalculateQuadraticBezierCurve(startPos, controlPos[cast.RayInfo.Count], endPos, alpha)
cast.StateInfo.Trajectories[1].Acceleration = tan
```

An approximation of calculating the curve length:

```lua
local function CalculateQuadraticBezierCurveLength(startPos, controlPos, endPos, numSegments)
    local length = 0
    local previousPoint = startPos

    for i = 1, numSegments do
        local t1 = (i - 1) / numSegments
        local t2 = i / numSegments

        local point1, tangent1 = CalculateQuadraticBezierCurve(startPos, controlPos, endPos, t1)
        local point2, tangent2 = CalculateQuadraticBezierCurve(startPos, controlPos, endPos, t2)

        length = length + (point2 - previousPoint).magnitude

        previousPoint = point2
    end

    return length
end
```

So what I do is I supply an intended speed and calculate the length of the Bezier curve, and use that to get the alpha on each frame to supply that into the position and tangent calculation. Unfortunately I can only change the acceleration, so based on some googled posts and help from ChatGPT (which wasn't too helpful to be honest), I used that tangent as the acceleration.

Here's a pic for some illustration; the green line is how setting the position works, and is thus a close approximation of the true Bezier curve, and the black line is what happens when using my implementation.
[Initial problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DCEj.png)
So naturally, since I input an acceleration the point on the line speeds up over time and breaks the curve. I want to keep a somewhat constant velocity despite the acceleration and follow the actual Bezier curve that I calculate.

So I have the problem of trying to put a Brezier curve in 3D space, and using the slope of the 2D curve to try and model that. So my main idea so far is to get that 2D plane within the 3D space on which the curve moves and correct the acceleration (tangent) for that. The image below shows what I mean visually.
[2D plane in 3D](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDaLD.png)

This is the code I add to the code when starting the curve:

```lua
local v = (FirePointObject.WorldPosition - TargetPos)
local CFrameLength = CFrame.new(TargetPos + 0.5 * v, FirePointObject.WorldPosition) * CFrame.fromOrientation(0, 0, math.rad(120 * i + 90))
local CFramePerpendicular = CFrameLength * CFrame.Angles(0, 0, math.rad(90))
mod[i] = Vector3.new(math.abs(CFramePerpendicular.UpVector.X), math.abs(CFramePerpendicular.UpVector.Y), math.abs(CFramePerpendicular.UpVector.Z))
```

It's a bit hard to put into words, but this mod[i] gives (per curve, as I make 3) the proportion of the 3 axes the 2D plane lies on.
The correction is simple:

```lua
cast.StateInfo.Trajectories[1].Acceleration = tan * mod[cast.RayInfo.Count]
```

Unfortunately, this does not give proper results; it makes the curve a bit more 'unpredictable', gives different endpoints (so compared to the earlier implentation, the velocity is not equal between curves) and the curve changes depending on with what direction I launch it (which was not the case with the previous implementation).
[Not a solution #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tgd3.jpg)
[Not a solution #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKuPG.png)

I am now a bit at a loss, also conceptually but since I'm pretty poor at math also in that department. Maybe I do have the right idea here, but just don't implement it properly. I really hope someone can help me here, or can give some closure if it is just impossible. Using the tangent of a "2D curve" as acceleration (which, again, is mandatory unless I completely change the FastCast module -which right now I can't) is just really weird and more difficult than possible, so I haven't quite found any similar case on the internet. Or I just don't understand any solutions that are on the internet (I'm a somewhat decent guy with luau, but that's honestly not enough at all combined with sucking at math).
I see this as a bit of a challenge by now, and honestly I'm also a bit frustrated with myself for not being able to figure it out.
So I really really hope someone can at least give some pointers, and I'd be happy to provide context or even the model directly if someone is actually interested to help me out.
Thank you in advance!

P.S. I made an account for this and thus a first time asker, hopefully this is properly done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The velocity is the derivative of the position function, and the acceleration is the derivative of the velocity. Given that you know the original quadratic function formula,

```
B_x(t) = p_x * (1-t)^2 + 2 * q_x * (1-t)t + r_x * t^2
B_y(t) = p_y * (1-t)^2 + ...
B_z(t) = p_z...
```

you also know the velocity, because the derivative of a Bezier curve is [just a lower order Bezier curve](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#derivatives):

```
B_x(t)' = p_x' * (1-t) + q_x' * t
B_y(t)' = p_y' * (1-t) + q_y' * t
B_z(t)' = p_z' * (1-t) + z_y' * t
```

where `p_x'` is `2 * (q_x - p_x)`, `q_x'` is `2 * (r_x - q_x)`, with the same applied to the y and z coordinates.

And similarly the acceleration is the derivative of *that*, which are just constants because it's the second derivative of a quadratic function.

```
B_x(t)'' = p_x''
B_y(t)'' = p_y''
B_y(t)'' = p_z''
```

where `p_x''` is `q_x' - p_x'`, and the same for the y coordinate.

Conveniently, the `t` in the Bezier formula is a time parameter, so you don't even have to do any crazy time reparameterization: you know the position, velocity, and acceleration at every moment in time along the Bezier curve.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Before I try and implement it, I got two questions. The first is, what did I calculate with the tan if not the derivative? And secondly, won’t the acceleration here just be constant? Should I change to a cubic Bézier curve to make this work?

Comment: Didn't say you weren't, what you called `tan` is the function derivative, but you were assigning it as if it were the acceleration, which it's not, it's the velocity. And yes, the acceleration will be constant, so if you want acceleration to vary you'll have to use a cubic (or higher, but you generally don't want anything higher than a cubic because you lose a bunch of useful properties once you do)

Comment: Since the direction of the point in 3D space has to change for it to actually form the curve, I do need a variable acceleration. Conceptually, it doesn't make sense why a quadratic Bezier curve would be impossible this way, but a cubic version would be.
I've by now already tried to use the change in velocity between points, but that gives an extremely large acceleration which screws up the velocity and curve even more, so that's no good either.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's not impossible, but by definition the acceleration along a quadratic curve (*any* quadratic curve) is a constant. That's simply how derivatives work. The question you should be asking is "what are you trying to actually do, and are Bezier curves the right curve for that" because if you need an object path, the original Bezier curve itself probably isn't, since you can draw the same path with an infinite number of Bezier curves by raising the order, all with _different_ derivatives. You generally want the function reparameterised for arc-length (which usually means "use a lookup table").

Comment: (Basically: Bezier curves are great for _drawing_ things, but they are _terrible_ for tracking paths because there is no "unique Bezier curve" for any given path with a single intuitive formula for the velocity along the path and a single intuitive formula for acceleration along the path)

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. Is there a different approach (curve) that is possible for such a thing? Or would the cubic Bezier curve properly work? I'm not good enough at all  to conceptually determine that, and before I put more time and frustration into something that won't (really) work. I will also make it arc-length parameterised, although I don't think that will fix this specific problem; but it will help generally, thank you!

Comment: Usually you use something like a Bezier path in order to get "the shape of the path", and then you turn it into a coordinate lookup table (either full or sparse, where you fill in the blanks as needed using interpolation) with each coordinate a known fixed distance apart, so that you can move things along that path at whatever velocity and acceleration you want.